# I fear this question might be too opinion based

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Here's the question:

> **Modernized dialogue in fantasy - stylistically untrue or clever genre subversion?**
>
> I find myself using words like "kiddo", "bullshit" and "badass" in the more comedic side of dialogue/thoughts in my fantasy novel. At first it was simply me not paying attention, and not caring as I knew I'd edit it out in a later draft. But upon reading a little of the writing, I found myself liking the contrast between modern speech and medieval-esque world. In an era of literary subversion, perhaps this is a welcoming addition? Or is this just stylistically untrue to the genre?

Quite simply, is this too opinion-based?

Comment: The question in, well, question, has been posted: [Modernized dialogue in fantasy - stylistically untrue or clever genre subversion?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/47248/2533)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that question is sufficiently well-defined to be answerable.

You aren't *just* asking for opinions. Sure, people will probably answer that to some degree based on opinions, but it's opinion *that can be backed up by fact, references, or expertise*. In such a case, it's not a problem.

Note the clarification for when to apply the "primarily opinion-based" close reason:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

(In our case, I'd even say "most" rather than "many", but that's a minor quibble.)

**If answers to a question can be supported by "facts, references, or specific expertise", then the primarily opinion-based close reason does not apply.**

Answer (score -2):

No. That question is perfectly fine.